# Show that $2009^n − 209^n − 839^n + 92^n$ is divisible by $117$ for each positive integer $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help on how to show that for each positive integer $n$, $2009^n − 209^n − 839^n + 92^n$ is divisible by $117$.

I have tried divisible rule but couldn't come up with anything meaningful.

Any help?

Comment: I will recommend a proof by induction...

Comment: Hint: what are $2009\bmod 117,209\bmod 117,$ and $839\bmod 117$?

Comment: Hint: $2009 \equiv 839 \mod 117$ and $209 \equiv 92 \mod 117$.

Comment: It might be easier to prove divisibility by 9 and 13 (because $117=9\cdot 13$).

Comment: @Robert, pearls before swine...

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3623463/589

Answer (score 0):

By using $$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+...+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}),$$ we obtain: $$2009^n-209^n-839^n+92^n=$$
$$=(2009-839)(2009^{n-1}+...+839^{n-1})-(209-92)(209^{n-1}+...+92^{n-1}).$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Thanks this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since $117=9\cdot 13$

So, it's sufficient to show that $9,13$ are divisors

$2009\equiv 2\mod 9$

$209\equiv 2\mod 9$

$839\equiv 2\mod 9$

$92\equiv 2\mod 9$

Hence,

$2009^n − 209^n − 839^n + 92^n\equiv 0\mod 9$

$2009\equiv 7\mod 13$

$209\equiv 1\mod 13$

$839\equiv 7\mod 13$

$92\equiv 1\mod 13$

Thus,

$2009^n − 209^n − 839^n + 92^n\equiv 0\mod 13$

Finally,

$2009^n − 209^n − 839^n + 92^n\equiv 0\mod 117$

Comment: Thank you so much this helps alot